# Inject urls into Apache Nutch from mysql instead of seed.txt

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am new to Apache Nutch and I want to inject urls dynamically from a mysql database. Does Apache Nutch offer such possiblity? If not, is there any similar experiment that i can learn from? Or any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

As Julien said you should modify INJECTOR code to achieve this. However, I can suggest a workaround for this. You can use NUTCH in server mode using command *bin/nutch startserver* and then load your seed urls from database. Then you can use Nutch REST API to create a seed list using urls loaded from database and point that created seed file to INJECT job creation service call.

You can find more details regarding REST api here :-

http://nutch.apache.org/miredot/1.12/index.html#1153761698 
or
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OGg22ATohapP2ycewIaTcUnENc2FeyYzni0ED_Jjxz8/edit
https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchRESTAPI

Answer (score 1):

Nutch 1.x => Not out of the box. You'd have to modify the Injector code so that it reads from MySQL but this is certainly doable. I did that for a customer ages ago.

Alternatively, you could use [StormCrawler](http://stormcrawler.net), it has a MySQL module and there should be no extra work to get it to work. The [Cloudsearch tutorial](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/index-web-with-aws-cloudsearch.html) on our blog shows how to use MySQL with SC.

Nutch 2.x uses GORA as an intermediate layer and IIRC there was a SQL plugin for it. Not sure of its status and whether this would be suitable.

Comment: Hi Julien, thanks for your answer. I am only interested in Nutch though. Yes there is a mysql plugin in Gora props for apache nutch 2.3.1, but I assume it is only for storing data and not for urls input. I am not sure what happens when I uncomment both, mysql and mongodb (in case I want to save results in mongodb only).

Comment: uncommenting both would probably result in a lovely mess I guess ;-). I'd stick to Nutch 1.x if I were you (better performance, less configuration etc... ) and write a custom Injector. You'd have to do the same with Nutch2.x anyway unless you used the same serialization with GORA to handle your seeds, which is probably not what you want.